# Component not mounting: React-Router 1.0.0-rc1 + Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a small prototype using React, Redux and React-Router 1.0.0-rc1. The prototype uses Webpack to do code splitting. It currently uses `getComponents` and `getChildRoutes` to async load additional routes like so:

```
module.exports = {
  path: 'donations',

  getChildRoutes(location, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, [
        require('./routes/Donation'),
      ]);
    });
  },

  getComponent(location, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('./components/Donations'));
    });
  }
};
```

This work fine, until I hit the nested route `donations/:id`, which looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  path: ':id',

  getComponents (location, cb) {
    console.log('got it', cb); // debugging
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      console.log('called it', cb); // debugging
      cb(null, require('./components/Donation'));
    });
  }
};
```

When I navigate to this route (ex: `/donations/123`), the route is triggered, the bundle.js file is loaded, and both `console.log`s appear in the console, so I know that the route was loaded up into memory. **However**, the component is not mounted and rendered.

Results of console.log:

```
got it function (error, value) {
      done(index, error, value);
    }
called it function (error, value) {
      done(index, error, value);
    }
```

Async routes one level deep are fine, but nesting past that doesn't work. The component is loaded, but it doesn't seem like it's executed.

The component that is returned is wrapped with Redux's `Connect` like so:

```
 function Connect(props, context) {
          _classCallCheck(this, Connect);
          _Component.call(this, props, context);
          this.version = version;
          this.store = props.store || c…
```

### Update: Problem solved

The issue was quite simple. Since this was a nested route, the Router was passing the nested component to its parent in `this.props.children`, which I wasn't checking for. Chalk it up to a mis-understanding of the (sparse) documentation for 1.0.0-rc1.

Comment: Can you write your solution as an answer and accept it? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how `react-router` works, in that when you're working with nested (child) routes the parent component needs to accommodate them as `this.props.children`:

**Before**

```
render() {
    let { DonationsComponent } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Donations</h2>
        <DonationsList donations={DonationsComponent} entities={entities} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In the above, `render` doesn't take into account `this.props.children`, so the nested route (Donation) was pulled in and connected, but not rendered.

```
render() {
    let { children, DonationsComponent, entities } = this.props
    let child = <DonationsList donations={DonationsComponent} entities={entities} />
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Donations</h2>
        {children || child}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Now, when `react-router` pulls in a nested route and passes it to `this.props.children`, the `render` function does the correct thing and renders `children` instead of `child`.

Comment: Had exactly the same misunderstanding. Was using https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit with fractal routes and I couldn't understand why the nested route I added didn't work like the others. Thanks for documenting your finding!